# Javascript counter speeds up after the second button click

Tags: javascript, html

I have a counter which is activated once `startnew` button is clicked:

```
<button id="startnew" onclick="counter()">Start new Game</button>

var i = 0;
function counter() {
  var execution = setInterval(function(){
    active() 
  }, 1000);
  function active() {
    i++;
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = i;
  }
}
```

The problem comes when I click on the `startnew` button for the second time, where counter starts to speed up as an inner variable stays the same. 
I have tried adding additional `if` clauses in different parts of a code which would check if a button was already clicked but had no success so far.

How can I reset an inner variable once the same button was clicked for a second time?

Comment: You're creating a new `setInterval` everytime you execute your `counter` function. That's the culprit who speeds up your `i`.

Comment: `function counter() { var i = 0; clearInterval(execution); ` declare your variable `i` inside the counter function. Also

Comment: So, as what choz said was correct, if you want to start a new game you should check to see if your instance is still working, if so set it to `null` and create a new instance. Edit: Also remember to set your `i` back to `0`.

Comment: Just call `clearInterval(execution)` before `setInterval` and have variable in `global-scope`

Comment: When you click the button again, it starts to call `active` twice which in turns add twice as much to `i`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new `setInterval` everytime you click the button.

Call `clearInterval(execution)` before `setInterval` and make var execution global. Also Declare your variable i inside the function counter.

```js
var execution;

function counter() {
  var i = 0;
  clearInterval(execution);

  execution = setInterval(function() {
    active()
  }, 1000);

  function active() {
    i++;
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = i;
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="startnew" onclick="counter()">Start new Game</button>
<br>
<span id="timer"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope i understood your Requirement...

Make the variable `execution` in Global Scope

```js
var i = 0;
var execution;

function counter() {
  if (i === 0) {
    execution = setInterval(function() {
      active()
    }, 1000);
  } else {
    clearInterval(execution);
    i = 0;
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = '';
  }

  function active() {

    i++;
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = i;

  }
}
```

```html
<button id="startnew" onclick="counter()">Start new Game</button>

<span id='timer'></span>
```